# Beeps on startup PC runs normally

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, cpu-usage

im trying to decode those sounds from my pc.
My pc runs normally but games always have 100% CPU usage regardless of the graphics settings.
Is it some CPU or RAM related problem?

beeps video
https://youtu.be/TGEDAvtVubg
I can hear 4 fast beeps and 1 also fast with different tone after a small interval of time

I also did run a short test with memcheck

MOBO Z390 AORUS ELITE
CPU i7 9700k 
GPU RTX3080
RAM Kingston 2300MHz 1x16GB

BIOS version - F10g
chipset updated yesterday

[test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nX8M.jpg)

Comment: Get the computer manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and run that. What does it tell you.

Comment: U mean gigabyte's diagnostic app?

Comment: If that is for the board, yes.  The diagnostic app should tell you what hardware component is causing the issue.

Comment: I found sth like this. Would this work?https://www.gigabyte.com/microsite/369/images/system-tweaking.html

Comment: See if that tells you what the error is. A computer should not beep like this when starting

Comment: Run memtest86+ from USB boot stick to check RAM. Beeping typically doesn't refer to CPU issues but you'd better check that CPU is not overheating.

Comment: Check beeps here: https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/threads/my-gigabyte-motherboard-beeps.60980/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - this motherboard doesnt like gddr6x. So I searched a bit more and found the solution - I had to disable CSM in the BIOS. Beeping is gone.

The framerate is the same because of the running in single channel instead of dual I guess. Ill get new 2x8GB 3200 sticks tommorow and tell if it fixed the problem with the fps.